# Enviar variáveis usando POST

Tags: actionscript-3, post

Estou tentando abrir uma nova URL e enviar variáveis via método `POST`, mas ele somente envia em método `GET`. Eu tentei esse Código:

```
// create a URLRequest object with the target URL:
var url : String = 'newpage.html';
var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

// create a URLVariables object and add all the values you want to send with their identifiers:
var urlVariables : URLVariables = new URLVariables();
urlVariables['formfieldId'] = 'formfieldValue';

// add the urlVariables to the urlRequest
urlRequest.data = urlVariables;

// set the method to post (default is GET)
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

// use navigateToURL to send the urlRequest, use '_self' to open in the same window
navigateToURL(urlRequest, '_self');
```

Tenho essa linha `urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;`
porem a URL não abre no método `POST` somente com método `GET`.
O que há de errado ?

Comment: O segundo site que pretende abrir é seu? Como o `navigateToURL` trata as variáveis apenas como `GET`, talvez seja interessante usar o SharedObject para criar alguns cookies como alternativa.

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente se você estiver executando um aplicativo na plataforma **Adobe AIR**, você não conseguirá enviar os valores por método `POST` pela função `navigateToURL`, pois ela irá tratar as variáveis como `GET`, segundo a documentação da própria Adobe, encontrada [aqui](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#method).

Se você estiver utilizando a plataforma do **Flash Player** na web, eu aconselho você realizar o teste com o arquivo SWF dentro do mesmo domínio do servidor com o código abaixo:

#### SWF:

```js
var url:String = "http://seudominio/teste.php";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var urlloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

variables.valor = "VALOR DE TESTE";
request.data = variables;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

navigateToURL(request);
```

#### PHP:

```php
<?php 

    $variavel = (isset($_POST["valor"]))?$_POST["valor"]:"erro";
    echo $variavel;

?>
```

Se funcionar no mesmo domínio e você precisar colocar seu swf em um domínio diferente, verifique as configurações de segurança do seu servidor. Mais detalhes [aqui](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29).

Os testes que realizei aqui funcionaram corretamente, utilizando inclusive um servidor local.

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque Para conteúdo em execução no Adobe AIR, ao usar a função navigateToURL(), o runtime trata um URLRequest que usa o método POST (um com a propriedade method definida como URLRequestMethod.POST ) por meio do método GET.

Por exemplo,

```
  public static const POST:String = "POST"
```

Coloque a variável loader:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
```

[Neste site](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestMethod.html#) existem mais informações;

Comment: eu quero abrir uma nova URL com variáveis no método POST.