# navigateToURL não está enviando POST

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

Ando a tentar enviar parâmetros do `actionscript` para o `php`, consultei a seguinte página:

**[Enviar variáveis usando POST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10273/enviar-vari%C3%A1veis-usando-post)**

Fiz direitinho, mas no momento que executa `navigateToURL(urlRequest, '_self');`, ele sempre mostra `erro` ao invés do esperado `VALOR DE TESTE`.

Já pesquisei muita informação mas apenas apresenta resultados de 2007 para baixo. Alguém sabe como passar um parâmetro de forma simples de `flash` para `php` (usando `POST` e não `GET`).

Comment: A sério?? então aqui vai. NO flash na primeira frame coloquei o código como no link acima e depois o ficheiro php que está no mesmo link, este: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10273/enviar-vari%C3%A1veis-usando-post Obrigado Guilherme lol.

Comment: Só pra constar, no SOpt tem várias perguntas sobre como passar dados de JS pra PHP, no final é praticamente a mesma coisa. Acho que vale à pena uma pesquisa.

Comment: Quero criar a variável no flash, envie para o php, abra o ficheiro php e mostre o valor da variável (não está fácil) na página em php.

Comment: e SOpt é o quê?

Comment: @dev Stack Overflow em Português... a pesquisa fica alí no canto de cima. De qualquer forma, acredito que a resposta postada resolva seu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao rodar o *script* pelo *Adobe Flash Profissional IDE* ao invés do navegador o programa irá converter `POST` para `GET` quando usar `navigateToURL(...);`, por este motivo você nunca irá obter o `VALOR DE TESTE` pois ele forçar a usar `GET`

### Usando POST com navigateToURL

Note que para usar `POST` é necessário (além de `req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;`)

- Mudar o `content-type` para `req.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`
- E codificar as variáveis assim `variables.valor = encodeURIComponent("VALOR DE TESTE");`

Deve ficar algo como:

```
var url:String = "http://localhost/post-test.php";
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

variables.valor = encodeURIComponent("VALOR DE TESTE");

req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
req.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.data = variables;

navigateToURL(req, "_blank");
```

Portanto para que `navigateToURL` funcione com `POST` você terá que colocar o `swf` embarcado em um HTML (supondo que o nome do arquivo seja *exemplo.html*):

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="meu-swf.swf"></object>
```

e rodar este HTML por um servidor como Apache, Ngnix ou lighttpd acessando:

```
http://localhost/exemplo.html
```

Irá aparecer uma mensagem falando que o pop-up foi bloqueado, mas então basta liberar conforme pedido do navegador para testar.

### Usando POST com URLLoader.load

O `navigationToURL` usa pop-up e isto pode ser um problema, principlamente por causa dos bloqueadores, eu recomendo fazer o processo usando somente `Flash` e `ActionScript`, em outras palavras não iremos abrir uma janela nova, uma maneira de fazer isto é usar `URLLoader.load`, exemplo de código (não misture com o outro script):

```
var url:String = "http://localhost/post-test.php";
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

variables.valor = encodeURIComponent("VALOR DE TESTE");

req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
req.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.data = variables;

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completo, false, 0, true);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError, false, 0, true);
urlLoader.load(req);

function completo(e:Event):void
{
    trace(urlLoader.data); // output: test
}

function ioError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace(e);
}
```

> **Note:** O uso de `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` é obrigatório

Para testar este códigos (tanto com `load` quanto com `navigateToURL`), você pode usar `var_dump` ou `print_r` no seu PHP, seria um tipo de depuração simples e manual, segue o PHP:

```
<?php
echo 'GET:', PHP_EOL;
print_r($_GET);

echo 'POST:', PHP_EOL;
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54639/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-navigatetourl-nao-esta-enviando-pos)